# Error [sObject.RecordType] Duplicate name 'sObjectRecordType' specified

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to create a Pull Request with code that i pulled from my scratch org, everything seems to work fine, but at the end this error appears:

[image: error capture]

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of sfdx are you using? And you haven't by any chance updated it between your pull and your push?!

Comment: Also having this issue, and I _think_ it might be related to having a recordtype and field with the same name in the custom object. In your case @martin-gamobo do you have a RT and a field both called "Modelo" on the "Case" object?